# Закрытие модального окна по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="form[ok]" class="rsform-submit-button">
```

Нужно по нажатию на неё закрыть модальное окно. Модальное окно - `$.colorbox()`. Оно закрывается следующим образом:

```
$.colorbox.close();
```

Я написал код:

```
function closeModal() {
    $.colorbox.close();
}
```

Вешаю на кнопку событие `onclick="closeModal()"`. Не работает. В консоли пишет:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: closeModal is not defined

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Проблема была в Iframe. Помог следующий код (закрывает окно вне iframe):

`onclick="parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()"`

Answer (score 0):

"Окно называется" - вы имеете ввиду, что оно имеет id='colorbox' ?
Если это так, то для закрытия попробуйте следующий код:

```
function closeModal() {
    $('#colorbox').close();
}
```

Comment: Нет, нет. Это не ID всплывающего окна. Таким образом закрывается, модальное окно. Цитата из документации `onclick="jQuery.colorbox.close();`

Comment: @Игорь: " Таким образом закрывается, модальное окно" - запятая сбивает с толку. Если ф-ция closeModal не определена, то попробуйте просто  onclick = "jQuery.colorbox.close();"

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode** из консоли

Comment: забыл поставить кавычки)
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined`

Comment: @Игорь: а целиком на код можно глянуть?

Comment: Это весь код, мб я, что-то делаю не так и здесь функция моя вообще не нужна.

Comment: Киньте ссылку на сайт сюда в комментарии.

Comment: @Игорь: этот colorbox использует iframe? откуда вы его взяли?
если да - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84023/closing-colorbox-after-submit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726532/jquery-colorbox-close-iframe-with-onclick-can-i-time-this-event

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите ваш код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeModal() {
    $.colorbox.close();
}
</script>
```

В конец файла (перед закрывающим тегом body )

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: closeModal is not defined`